# How standard is the Liturgy of the Hours from the Word on Fire?

Tags: catholicism, liturgy-of-the-hours

I very much like the Word on Fire Liturgy of the Hours booklets, I think it's helped me a lot in getting to do things in a most consistent and concise fashion that I'd only be able to pick up on if I lived in a monastic community (which ain't happening any time soon), my question is though, there are several things that augment my standard issue Liturgy of the Hours books.  I've got three  versions (Common Prayer with hymns, a large type one and the 4 volume one with the Office of Readings) I'd like some sort of commentary on what might be the reasoning for each of these things, I'm leaving off things I understand, like the optionality of Psalm Prayers.

1. There's no Invitatory Psalm or Antiphon
2. The Lord's Prayer is in English and Latin, why?
3. There's no preface to the Lord's Prayer as in the Ordinary
4. Night Prayer has "Let Us Pray" before the final prayer, but the rest of the hours do not
5. Feast days use the antiphons AND psalms from the 4 week psalter, but memorials (like today, the Beheading of St. John the Baptist) use the Week 1 Sunday.  When would you use the antiphons from the proper of Holy Women, Martyrs, etc..?
6. On Sunday Evening prayer, there are lots of Alleluia's even between the parts of the Doxology, is that normal?